# Can you help explain the following construct in d3.....packages.root(classes)?

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

Can you explain the following in d3?

```
var nodes = cluster.nodes(packages.root(classes)),
    links = packages.imports(nodes);
```

I can't seem to find the proper information on the `packages.root` and `packages.imports`.
I think I know what the code is doing.

This is from the bundle-radial.js in the d3 examples.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page in question?

Comment: @Brant OlsenSorry here is the link [link](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/bundle/bundle-radial.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `packages` object is defined in [packages.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/bundle/packages.js), which each of the bundle example html files includes ahead of their respective `bundle-X.js`.